# When I call next fragment form current the tab selection will not change on Button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an android app in which I am going to include tab with fragment. Please find below code for Activity :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class EnterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).select();
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new EnterCodeFragment(), "ENTER CODE");
    adapter.addFragment(new HistoryFragment(), "HISTORY");
    adapter.addFragment(new HelpFragment(), "HELP");
    adapter.addFragment(new LogoutFragment(), "LOGOUT");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Below logic I used to call other fragment on button click.

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        Button loginButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = new EnterCodeFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
             //   ViewPagerAdapter.get
            }
        });
        return v;
        }
```

When I click on button it will move to the next fragment but tab selection will not change. **I think it is creating a new fragment**. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you are adding this line in onCreate " tabLayout.getTabAt(3).select(); "

Comment: @Omi Actually I need to set default tab when starting the activity. So I added that line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not initialize fragment properly update like above code

```
 Button loginButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            EnterCodeFragment fragment = new EnterCodeFragment(); // check this 

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
             //   ViewPagerAdapter.get
            }
        });
```